# How do I properly hook into Json.NET's JObject.ToObject<T>()?

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net, json-deserialization

I have a data structure with several nested types.

```
public class MyDataType {
    public int InferrableInt { get; set; }
    public float InferrableFloat { get; set; }
    public InferrableNestedDataType MyINDT { get; set; }
    public CustomNestedDataType MyCNDT { get; set; }

    public class InferrableNestedDataType {
        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
    }
    public class CustomNestedDataType {
        // Data processed in a way that can't be expressed through JSON
        public string CustomData { get; set; }

        public int NestedInferrableInt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Most of these nested types can be inferred by the default behaviour.

I also have a `JObject` received from another part of the code. I would like to be able to:

```
var mydt = jobjectInstance.ToObject<MyDataType>()
```

... and only run custom code when deserializing `MyDataType.CustomNestedDataType`. Every solution I've found has extended `JsonConverter`, but as far as I can tell this only works when parsing from raw JSON, and not a pre-parsed `JObject`. What is the proper way to do this, without writing custom code for the inferrable datatypes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Every solution I've found has extended JsonConverter, but as far as I can tell this only works when parsing from raw JSON

It should work with `JObject.ToObject` as well. You have at least two options:

- Apply the `JsonAttributeConverter` attribute to your class to specify the converter to use:

  ```
  [JsonConverter(CustomNestedDataTypeConverter)]
  public class CustomNestedDataType
  ```

  (if it's just `CustomNestedDataType.CustomData` that needs custom serialization, write a converter for that and apply the attribute to the property)
- Create a `JsonSerializer` with your converter, and pass it to `JObject.ToObject`:

  ```
  var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
  serializer.Converters.Add(new CustomNestedDataTypeConverter());

  var result = jObject.ToObject<MyDataType>(serializer);
  ```

Comment: Aha, makes sense. Thank you!